# Why router can't be used for converting different model of network but gateway can do this?

Tags: router, ip, tcp, layer3, osi

We know that Router can't be used for converting different model (e.g **OSI model** to **TCP/IP** or **TCP/IP model** to **OSI**) of network. It isn't a multiprotocol converter. But gateway is a highly sophisticated router which can be used for connecting different model of network. I have been finding actual reason behind this but failed to find any fruitful stuff. Can anybody help to make out above concepts.

Comment: Router and Gateway are defined based on their capabilities and how they work. If a router would be defined differently it could do other things. So you are basically asking why specific capabilities are called a specific name. Note also that meaning can change over time, i.e.  what is today called a router is way more than what was traditionally called a router.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding a few things. OSI model is used today mostly as a reference, TCP/IP is the name of the game. Any router that is forwarding traffic between a subnet and the rest of the world is a "gateway". You can configure a RasPi to forward traffic into and out of a subnet with 2 static routes, in which case it's a gateway for that subnet. An example of OSI protocol is IS-IS, which for example Cisco routers support. They can also FW between between RS-232 and TCP/IP. So please expand your question, add some examples from real life to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Models are models - concepts for thought. Like philosophies - sometimes one fits better, some other time the other one.

*Converting between TCP/IP model and OSI model* doesn't make sense. It's like trying to convert a glass that's half full to a glass that's half empty. It's only a matter of perspective.

The OSI and TCP/IP models are actually very similar. OSI is more detailed (and more theoretical), and TCP/IP focuses on the *network* (OSI)/*internet* (IP) and the *transport layer*, naturally. OSI splits IP's *application layer* into *application*, *presentation* and *session* (not too common in real life), and IP's *link layer* is represented by OSI's *data link* and *physical layers* (very useful in practice).

On the network layer, *router* and *gateway* are the very same thing. There are various feature levels (concerning filtering, firewalling, inspection, address translation, ...) but both terms are interchangeable still.

*Gateway* can also refer to various other concepts that connect different realms. Gateways from different OSI layers (bridges, routers, proxies, application-layer gateways, ...) are generally different, but even gateways working in the same layer can be vastly different.

Higher-layer gateways can even be used to translate between protocols with a similar purpose, like an FTP-over-HTTP proxy. But all that is off-topic here for working above the transport layer.

Comment: please correct the spelling of "glas"

Comment: please elaborate little bit "Higher-layer gateways can even be used to translate between similar protocols, like an FTP-over-HTTP proxy". Here FTP and htttp similar protocol?

Comment: No, FTP and HTTP are completely different. However, some HTTP proxies support `GET ftp://server/path` requests.

Comment: why you written "similar protocol"? Actually I don't understand this line..

Comment: They're similar in that they both can be used to transfer files. But they work completely differently.

Comment: You should write **transfer** instead of **translate**.

Comment: That proxy *translates* between FTP (server-side) and HTTP (client-side) for *transferring* files.

Comment: Here proxy is gateway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129734/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-zac67).

Comment: @zac67.....what does mean of http proxy? It is gateway?

Answer (score 5):

I would dare say that you are the victim of the simplistic view presented by network 101 (introduction to networking) courses.

Let me start by quoting from ISO 7498 (the OSI reference model).

> The purpose of this Reference Model of Open Systems Interconnection is to provide a common basis for the coordination of standards development for the purpose of systems interconnection, while allowing existing standards to be placed into perspective within the overall Reference Model.

Therefore, it's not a technology, nor is it an architecture, but a reference against which to build and compare architectures.

I would continue by pointing out that gateway and router have been used interchangeably. RFC 791, the original RFC behind IP, defines the gateway as follows:

> Gateways implement internet protocol to forward datagrams between
> networks.  Gateways also implement the Gateway to Gateway Protocol
> (GGP) [7] to coordinate routing and other internet control
> information.

Today, gateway is too overloaded to have any real meaning, without a full context being given. On the other hand, the term router has a sharper profile. Primarily, it is an IP packet switch, that switches a packet from an ingress port to an egress port according to the rules it has gathered into the forwarding information base (FIB). Traditionally, and still widely valid, the source of the rules is the data exchanged through the use of a routing protocol and processed by a routing algorithm. The result of the processing is stored in a routing information base (RIB). The router selects a specific entry from the RIB, according to configured criteria, for inclusion in the FIB.

To give one example of the use of gateway, there is an application-level gateway (ALG) used in network address and port translation (NAPT). The ALG inspects the protocol data unit (PDU) relevant to the application (e.g. active FTP) and converts private address information embedded in the PDU into public address information, to enable the function of FTP applications across a NAPT device.

Comment: Erm... An ALG doesn't really have *any* relation to NAPT. A NAPT gateway translates between different address domains (usually private and public IP) on the network and transport layers. An ALG inspects and filters (and possibly manipulates) traffic on the application layer. Both can be used entirely independently of each other.

Comment: Not sure about your comment. Are you sure we aren't getting caught up in another round of terminological overload? I've seen ALG used for this specific example.

Comment: In that scenario, an ALG is likely more a proxy than a NAPT gateway.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. The function I've described is transparent; proxies I'm aware of (at this very moment, at least) are visible in the end-to-end path.

Comment: Proxies can also be transparent. Pretty much any decent firewall has that option.

Comment: I think we're chasing thin air. What I pointed out is that an ALG is used in NAPT. Here's an example: https://www.3cx.com/pbx/alg/. I don't quite follow what you're understanding when you write that "An ALG doesn't really have any relation to NAPT". Perhaps you thought that I was implying that ALG is part of NAPT? Would it help if I were to explicitly state that ALG is used in NAPT devices to enable the use of specific applications?

Comment: I was trying to point out that using an ALG for NAPT isn't its main function. But let's agree to disagree on that, it's not bringing the topic along here. ;-)

Comment: No worries :) I confess I was taken aback by your original disassociation between NAPT and ALG, but I will agree with you that  ALG is not integral to NAPT, i.e. it is a separate network function. I would qualify by saying that it's a typical complementary function to NAPT in a device that does perform NAPT. The examples I pointed to in the link are routine in what I've encountered in the field. Thank you for taking the time to discuss this with me.